# Unable to use twitter-api as a tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

For some reason I am unable to use [twitter-api](/questions/tagged/twitter-api) on Stack Overflow. Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix/get round it? Is it a website error?

To clarify, it allows me to type it in on the tags, but as soon as I save edits or post the question the tag disappears?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[twitter-api](/questions/tagged/twitter-api) is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter/synonyms) of [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter).

Whenever you use [twitter-api](/questions/tagged/twitter-api), it will be replaced with [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter) - and if you already have [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter), it will be removed (no duplicate tags).

Comment: They can't be used in-conjunction with eachother then?

So how can `Python` and `Python-2.7` or `Python-3.x` be used in-conjunction and be allowed?

Comment: @Hyflex - The python tags are not synonyms (or at least, no one has defined them as such).

Comment: @Hyflex: Because Python != Python 2.7 != Python 3.0. In contrast to Twitter, because if you have a question about Twitter it can only be about the API, everything else would be off-topic on SO.

Comment: It got me too in the past, I must admit it wasn't easy to understand even when I was familiar with the synonym mechanism in general. Can the UI be improved somehow to add message like "this is a synonym and can't be added directly"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd silent, seamless translation is the point, otherwise "synonyms" could be dropped in favour of simple tag ban. I would like to see a message after save, like " Tag X was synonym of Y, replaced for you", or "Tags X and Y are synonyms, Y removed".